# Simple question related to Correlation & Covariance

Tags: statistics, random-variables, covariance, correlation

$X$ and $Y$ are two random variables with $\Bbb E[X] = \Bbb E[Y] = 1$ and $\Bbb E[X^2] = \Bbb E[Y^2] = 2$. Which of the following is not possible:

1. $\Bbb E[XY] > 0$
2. $\Bbb E[XY] < 0$
3. $\Bbb E[XY] = 0$
4. $\Bbb E[XY] \le 2$

I reached the following conclusions:

- $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = \Bbb E[XY] - \Bbb E[X]\Bbb E[Y] = \Bbb E[XY]-1$
- $\operatorname{Var}(X) = \Bbb E[X^2] - \Bbb E[X]^2 = \operatorname{Var}(Y) = 1$
- $\operatorname{Corr}(X,Y) = \operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$
- I noticed that this value is the maximum value for both correlation and covariance since $$\operatorname{Corr}(X,Y)=\frac{\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)\operatorname{Var}(Y)}}$$ and $\operatorname{Corr}(X,Y) = \Bbb E[XY]-1$ but I still did not reach a conclusion regarding $\Bbb E[XY]$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Rather $E(XY)=1+\operatorname{Corr}(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the correlation $\rho=\Bbb E[XY]-1$ and $|\rho|\le1$, we must have $0\le\Bbb E[XY]\le2$ so the second option is not possible.

Comment: The first option is possible: take $X=1+U$ and $Y=1+V$ where $U,V$ are i.i.d. standard normal.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I copied the wrong expression for $\rho$, see now